# Working with frame in Page Object Model using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

How would be work with frame in page object model with TestNG Framework in selenium Webdriver?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to create a new PageObject for the frame and return it when you switch to the frame (to work with frame you have to switch to it http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/handling-iframes-using-selenium-webdriver/)

**So steps you have to do are:**

1. Create page object for your frame
2. Create method that allows you to switch to the frame and returns your page object